# How to calculate $P(A)$ given only $P(A|B)$ , $P(A|B')$ and $P(B)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes

Assume $A$ and $B$ are two dependant events with only the following details provided

$P(A|B)$, $P(A|\neg B)$ and $P(B)$

How to calculate the value of $P(A)$?

Comment: Once you know $P(B)$, you can find P(-B)$. You should also check the law of total probability which will help you to finding $P(A)$.

Comment: @MattBrems: Thanks. I'm clear now. I've posted the complete answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer.

By the definition of conditional probability,

$P(A | B) = P(A \cap B) / P(B)$

$\implies P(A \cap B) = P(A|B).P(B)$

$P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap \neg B)$

Hence

$P(A) = P(A|B).P(B) + P(A|\neg B).P(\neg B)$

where$\quad P(\neg B) = 1 - P(B)$

Comment: That's exactly correct.